# Nothing to be done for dev makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a simple Makefil here:

```
.PHONY: dev

dev:
        php -S localhost:8000
```

And this error comme out: Nothing to be done for dev

Answer (score 0):

The only way this could be happening is if make can't find your makefile.  Are you in the same directory as this makefile when you run `make`?  Did you name your makefile `makefile` or `Makefile`, or did you call it something else?  In your question you say you have *a simple Makefil* but I don't know if that was a typo or if you really tried to call your makefile "Makefil" (missing final "e").

See [the GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Makefile-Arguments.html) for information on how make locates makefiles.